# Running an ASP.NET Core Pipeline using Azure Functions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, razor-pages

This was posted back in August https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/c3e9f882-541f-48a2-a856-956ad3383f67/running-an-aspnet-core-pipeline-using-azure-functions

He talks about using a catch-all function and then somehow running the HttpRequestMessage through Asp.Net Core

How can I do this? With functions 2, using core, I can do things like add a Razor Page to my functions app. But if I try to return the View it throws an internal server error.

How can I call a Controller myself, and then get an IActionResult value back?

Comment: Seems like a hack to me. The Functions use-case is to get in and get out quickly, whereas a framework like ASP.NET is designed with a lot of one-time startup overhead with the expectation it'll continue running for quite awhile. Bear in mind, too, that part of the consumption plan is CPU/memory usage -- you probably waste more money on startup than on the actual workload you're processing. So, I'm not sure "how" but I'm sure it's a bad idea.

Comment: @McGuireV10 there will be no initialization overhead for each request as the framework will be initialized once for every function instance. At least if this implementation is used https://blog.kabrt.cz/posts/2018-11-serverless-asp-net-mvc